# Как сделать такой эффект в html css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

у меня не получается сделать шапку как на этом фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А именно у меня не получается сделать такой эффект с картинкой. Пытался использовать radial-gradient() у меня не получилось.

Comment: Не вижу никакого эффекта.

Comment: @Qwertiy там идет затемнение справа налево

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите просто градиент затемнения слева-направо?

Если да, то можно ваше фото поместить в `div` и для его `::after` назначить следующие стили (подрегулировать их, если нужно):

```
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, transparent);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Демо: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-w82xbz?file=index.html,style.css,index.js

*Не забыть добавить `position: relative` для самого `div`, чтобы градиент не выходил за его рамки